# Como colocar uma border / stroke num <image> em um SVG?

Tags: html5, imagem, svg

Eu preciso adicionar um `stroke` ao redor de um `<image>` dentro de um `<svg>`. Porém não acontece nada ao adicionar o valor nessa tag.

Veja abaixo o que acontece: quando uso no `<image>` não funciona, porém no `<rect>` funciona.

Exemplo:

```css
.my-svg{
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="my-svg">
  <image y="0" x="0" height="100" width="100" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJaft.jpg" />
</svg>

<svg class="my-svg">
  <rect height="50" width="50"></rect>
</svg>
```

Nesse caso, o que poderia ser feito para se inserir um `stroke` na imagem?

Comment: Publiquei uma resposta uma resposta sem querer :/ , querer executar snipped e cliquei sem pensar. De qualquer maneira, vê se isto te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217669/svg-image-with-a-border-stroke

Comment: @Miguel publica ela traduzida para nóis ;p

Comment: Estou a trabalhar nisso, isto agora é pessoal lol, orgulho fala alto agora

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possivel se vc usar um `pattern` dentro do svg linkando a imagem no shape (rect, polygon, circle, até no path funciona).

Primeiro vc cria a definição `<defs>` depois o `<pattern>` e coloca a imagem que vai ser o BG `<image>` Depois vc usa a pattern-img como `fill` do elemento `fill="url(#ID-do-pattern)"`

Veja no exemplo para entender melhor.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg2" version="1.1" width="900px" height="611px" viewBox="0 0 900 611">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="p2" x="0" y="0" height="1" width="1">
            <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="https://unsplash.it/300/300"></image>
        </pattern>
    </defs>

    <rect x="0" y="0" width="300px" height="100px" fill="url(#p2)" stroke="black" />

    <rect x="0" y="110" width="150" height="200" fill="url(#p2)" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" />

    <circle cx="250" cy="200" r="70" fill="url(#p2)" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3"/>

    <polygon points="300,300, 250,390, 180,420, 100,400, 200,270" fill="url(#p2)" stroke="green" stroke-width="4"/>

    <path d="M350 400 L475 300 L225 200 Z" fill="url(#p2)" stroke="red" stroke-width="8" />
</svg>
```

[Link que usei de base para fazer](https://css-tricks.com/background-image-shapes/)

Comment: Gostei do placecage, kkkkk

Comment: @WallaceMaxters na próxima vou usar aquela foto do Caetano Veloso :D